# How to properly update a state records in reacts

Tags: reactjs

The Code below successfully displays record from Atlassian Jira Storage API

```
//import goes here

const fetchRec = async () => {
  const data = await storage.query().where('key', startsWith('Mykeysxxxxx')).getMany();
  return data.results;
};

const App = () => {
  const [projects] = useState(fetchRec);

  return (
    <div>
      // display or map projects records here
      {projects.map(project => (
        <div>
          <b>Fullname: {project.fullname}</b>

          <b>Email: {project.email}</b>

        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Here is my Issue.** I need to refresh the Records when new data is inserted.
So I implemented the code below. when I click on refresh Records button, the new inserted record is not updated

```
<Button text="Refresh Records" onClick={async () => { await reloadRec(); }} />

async function reloadRec() {
  fetchRec().then(projects);
  //const [projects] = useState(async () => await fetchRec());
}
```

**Here is the full code efforts so far**

```
// Import goes here
const fetchRec = async () => {
  const data = await storage.query().where('key', startsWith('Mykeysxxxxx')).getMany();
  return data.results;
};


async function reloadRec() {
  fetchRec().then(projects);
  //const [projects] = useState(async () => await fetchRec());
}

const App = () => {
  const [projects] = useState(fetchRec);

  return (
    <div>
      // display or map projects records here
      {projects.map(project => (
        <div>
          <b>Fullname: {project.fullname}</b>

          <b>Email: {project.email}</b>

        </div>
      ))}

      <Button text="Refresh Records" onClick={async () => { await reloadRec(); }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
async function reloadRec() {
  fetchRec().then(projects);
  //const [projects] = useState(async () => await fetchRec());
}
```

In the above function, `projects` is undefined.  And even if it was the same variable as defined in the `App` function, it's not a function that the `then` clause would invoke.

I think this is closer to what you want and follows the standard practices.

```
const App = () => {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);

  const fetcher = async () => {
    const data = await storage.query().where('key', startsWith('Mykeysxxxxx')).getMany();
    setProjects(data.results);
  };

  // do the initial fetch with an effect
  useEffect(() => {
    fetcher();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      // display or map projects records here
      {projects.map(project => (
        <div>
          <b>Fullname: {project.fullname}</b>

          <b>Email: {project.email}</b>

        </div>
      ))}

      <Button text="Refresh Records" onClick={fetcher} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @selbie for getting back to me. When I implemented your solution,  When the App initially loads, no record is displayed but when I click on Refresh button, it will display records. please can you help me further.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in both `fetcher` and in `useEffect` to confirm it gets invoked when your app initially loads.  You did add the `useEffect` statement, right?

Comment: Add `console.log` statements in both the useEffect and fetcher functions can be helpful as well. So you can see if `setProjects` is getting invoked with the data you think it should.

Answer (score 0):

InOrder to update information on the DOM you should update a state and DOM will show latest information. You bind and setRecord with fetchData function

**Extanding**

```
const App = () => {
  const [projects,setProjects] = useState([]);

  const fetchRecords = async() => {
     const data = await /*... your data base query  */
     // Assuming projects is an array of project
     setProjects(data.projects);
  }
  

  useEffect(()=>{
     fetchRecords();
  },[])

  return (
    <div>
      // display or map projects records here
      {projects.map(project => (
        <div>
          <b>Fullname: {project.fullname}</b>

          <b>Email: {project.email}</b>

        </div>
      ))}

      <Button text="Refresh Records" onClick={fetchRecords} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

So at first when Component is mount you will see Projects list and then when you click on reload fetchRecords is again called resulting in state change and will reflect on dom

Comment: Thanks for your response., please can you provide code sample on that